# How to import to rake file to table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

hi i m new to ROR i need to how to import following data to table City in Database
This file is in libs>>tasks>>

```
desc "Import City to  ActiveRecord table"
task :city_import, [:argument] => :environment do

 puts "Importing City ***"

        City.create(:name=>'Balaghat',:state_id=>State.find_by_name('Madhya Pradesh'));
        City.create(:name=>'Belgaum',:state_id=>State.find_by_name('Karnataka'));
end
```

i try to using rake in terminal but not working

Comment: try running "rake -T" in your terminal. See whether your task name appears in that list.

Comment: Is it showing your task name in that list?

Comment: What is the output if you type rake city_import in your Terminal?

Comment: working some spacing problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal go to your app and type

```
 rake city_import
```